# How to call repository method in entity listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

I'm trying to make call to repository inside my Entity Listener, when I call repository.findById() method inside my @prePersist method the same method is calling multiple time and I'm getting null pointer exception :

Here is code :

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    public MyListener () {
        
    }
    
    private static MyRepo myRepo;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyRepo(MyRepo myRepository) {
        MyListener.myRepo= myRepository;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void preUpdate(MyEntity myEntity ) {
        
        MySecondEntity mySecondEntity = myRepo.findById(true);

        if(! myEntity.value.equals(mySecondEntity.getValue())) {
            myEntity.setNewValue(mySecondEntity.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({MyListener .class})
public class MyEntity {
    //properties goes here
}
```

So my requirement here to get a value from one table and check with the entry in MyEntity table and save it before any save or update in MyEntity table. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: just added error message

Comment: Maybe should have been more specific. A stack trace. What you posted doesn't tell much.

Comment: added the complete log

Comment: Why is your repo `static` ?

Comment: If I'm not using static there is not not autowireing, I'm getting bean null

Comment: I am also working on similar requirement and also facing the same issue ie, repo method is getting called multiple times and finally getting stackoverflow exception. Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: No, I was not able to find the solution, I modified my approach

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NPE because `MyListener` is getting instantiated by Hibernate and not Spring AOP, thus `MyRepo` cannot be Autowired.
I am not sure that a solution exists for what you are trying to do.

The best solution would be to change your approach.